# Angular 7 Print Service

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to print the angular form for which I came across this example : 
https://stackblitz.com/github/IdanCo/angular-print-service?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I have gone through the named routes but this concept was not clear
I was stucked at two points :

1. In app.component.html , what is [class.isPrinting] & what it's doing ?

```
<div [class.isPrinting]="printService.isPrinting"> 

// printService.isPrinting is set to false
```

2. In app.routing.module.ts , we are using print outlet with children as invoice routes
   For the same in html , we can see 
      // will display printlayout ???
     // this will display my invoice routes which are child routes

3, In print-layout.component.html, we have one more  what this actually display / does

Thank You !

Answer (score 2):

```
<div [class.isPrinting]="printService.isPrinting"> 
// printService.isPrinting is set to false
```

Answer to this question is isPrinting is a css class which will be applied to the div if the  printService.isPrinting  is true. Currently it is false so the class will not be applied.

Apart from that for other questions I would advice to go through angular concepts in details and try using them.

Comment: Got it ! Thank You Tuhin